# CSS change content on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some icons in my content and I want if I hover over one of icon, will so something like round images around the icon, or the icon will become bigger :

[image]

I tried :

```
.pic2
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    left:64%;
    bottom:44%;
}

.pic2:hover{
background-image:url("slicingimages/media/icon_highlight.png");
}
```

my content :

```
   <div id="content">
        <p2>
            <content class="contentUpper"><img src="SlicingImage/Images/alacards_coupons_illustration.png"> </img></content>
            <content class="text" id="user2">ONE PLACE TO GET REWARDS</content>
            <div><img class="pic2" src="SlicingImage/Media/gift_icon.png" height="8%" width="4%"><img></div>
            <div><img class="pic4" src="SlicingImage/Media/browser_icon.png" height="8%" width="4%"></img></div>
            <div><img class="pic5" src="SlicingImage/Media/twitter_icon.png" height="8%" width="4%"></img></div>
            <div><img class="pic6" src="SlicingImage/Media/facebook_icon.png" height="8%" width="4%"></img></div>
            <content class="text" id="user4">FROM YOUR LOYAL BRANDS</content>
            <div><a href="#" id="user" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example10');return false;">
            <img class="back" src="SlicingImage/prev_button.png"></a></img></div>
            <div><a href="#" id="user" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example12');return false;">
            <img class="next" src="SlicingImage/next_button.png"></img></a></div>
            <content class="text" id="homeNext"> With all your loyality card, reward points, coupons & discount vouchers </div>
        </p2>    
   </div>
```

Comment: CSS isn't used to change HTML Attributes. Use Javascript.

Comment: Its not change the images actually, but add images **icon_highlight.png** below the **gift_icon.png**

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because for .pic2 there is a image tag in the html. Which takes up the whole element. So the background on hover is working correctly, it's just not showing up because the image is in front of it!

In order for this to work, with just CSS, you would need to use background image instead of html image tag.

For example you would delete this

```
<img src="SlicingImage/Media/gift_icon.png" height="8%" width="4%">
```

and add this to .pic2

```
.pic2
{
    background-image: url("SlicingImage/Media/gift_icon.png");
}
```

and keep .pic2:hover the same

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show a bigger image on hover of smaller one? If this is your question then, you can try below `CSS`.

```
.thumbnail
{
    background-image:url('/somesmallimgpath.png');
}


.thumbnail:hover
{
    background-image:url('/somebigimgpath.png');
}
```

Comment: I want if i Hover over **gift_icon.png**, below this pic will add "icon_highlight.png", can I accomplish that using CSS only?

Comment: If you want the hover for only one image then yes you can. But if want this logic to get applied for all the images then, you can maintain all the names of images as imagename.png and larger image name as imagename_highlight.png and set the CSS from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using Image Sprites (like your image containing multiple icons) and swapping one icon for another icon when hovering.

You need to remove the foreground image and just use background images (otherwise it will be shown over the background image and you won't see any change). When you make this change then there is no particular need to use an `IMG` tag as you can apply the background image to anything.

You can see it in action in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hWfZg/16/).

```
.pic2{
    background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOxx3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left -16px center;
    display: inline-block;
    width:  46px;
    height: 46px;
    margin: 23px;
}
.pic2:hover{
    background-position: left -178px center;
    width: 92px;
    height: 92px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
.pic2:hover{
       border:5px;
       //Your code
  }
```